# nvidia driver - stuttering / audio lag

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, nvidia-geforce

Im using ubuntu 20.04 lts with nvidia 465.27.  recently i realized that my gaming performance is awful. I mainly play OSU and audio delay with stuttering is insane. there is no problem on other parts of the laptop. i can't use nvidiXsettings app. it straight up shows me prime profiles. and i cant use `nvidia-smi` command. I tried fixing both of them via google but i just couldn't do it without another hand of help. i also tried removing-reinstalling the nvidia driver. still didn't work.

```
lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev ff)
```

and

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

.

```
sudo nvidia-settings
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:123468): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:06:07.282: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 14:06:07.285: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 14:06:07.285: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 14:06:07.318: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 14:06:07.318: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 14:06:07.318: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

still beginner to linux. if any other command output you need...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go back to the 460 driver. You can go to "software and updates" menu and select the option nvidia-driver-460.

I have the same gpu as you, and using this driver everything is working fine.